# How to use case_when() on a list with apply or map

Tags: r, dplyr, apply

I am trying to use the dplyr function `case_when()` on a list of annotation so I can assign the name of the marker to my data. I've found a way to do this manually by writing it several times but I tried applying it to a list with apply or map and didn't find a solution.

Here is a reproductible example :

```r
library(tidyverse)
annotation <- list (marker_1 = c("L", "D"),
                    marker_2 = c("C","R"),
                    marker_3 = c("A", "B"),
                    marker_4 = c("E", "F"),
                    marker_5 = c("G", "H"))


df <- tibble(L = 1, D = 2, C = 3, R = 4)


annotation_df <-
  tibble(markers = colnames(df)) %>%
  mutate(
    type = case_when(
      markers %in% annotation[[1]] ~ names(annotation[1]),
      markers %in% annotation[[2]] ~ names(annotation[2]),
      markers %in% annotation[[3]] ~ names(annotation[3]),
      markers %in% annotation[[4]] ~ names(annotation[4]),
      markers %in% annotation[[5]] ~ names(annotation[5])
    )
  ) %>%
  column_to_rownames("markers")
print(annotation_df)
#>       type
#> L marker_1
#> D marker_1
#> C marker_2
#> R marker_2
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `case_when`, a more easier option is a join after converting the named `list` to a two column `tibble` with (`tibble::enframe`)

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(tibble)
enframe(annotation, name = 'type', value = 'markers') %>% 
   unnest(markers) %>%
    right_join(tibble(markers = colnames(df))) %>%
   relocate(type, .after = 'markers')
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 × 2
  markers type    
  <chr>   <chr>   
1 L       marker_1
2 D       marker_1
3 C       marker_2
4 R       marker_2
```

---

Or another opition is to loop over the `list`, get the `intersect`ing elements and convert the named list to `tibble`

```
library(purrr)
map(annotation, ~ intersect(names(df), .x)) %>%
  keep(lengths(.) > 0) %>%
  enframe(name = 'markers', value = 'type') %>%
  unnest(type)
```

---

Or using `base R` with `lapply` and `stack`

```
lapply(annotation, \(x) intersect(names(df), x)) |>
    Filter(length, x = _) |>
    stack() |> 
    setNames(c("markers", "type")) |>
    subset(select = 2:1)
```

-output

```
      type markers
1 marker_1       L
2 marker_1       D
3 marker_2       C
4 marker_2       R
```